# How to make a module function use a locally named variable as a default parameter?

Tags: python, function

I use the following function in several scripts in my project folder:

```
verbose_print = config["verbose"].getboolean('print')

def verbose(text, *args, **kwargs):
    if verbose_print: print(text, *args, **kwargs)
    return None
```

`verbose_print` is a boolean value I get from a single config file when executing the script (every script shares the same config file).

This project folder has a "helper functions" `lib` folder which acts as a local package of modules.

Since it is rather ugly to define this same function at the top of every script (after `verbose_print` has been established), I wonder if there's any clean and hopefully elegant way to add it to the `lib` folder to make it use the `verbose_print` variable when imported to any of these scripts. Using `locals()` and searching for a variable with that desired name is the only solution I can think of, but I'm looking for better, cleaner solutions if possible so I can leave a clean codebase for when I quit.

P.s.: it's a small startup data science team, so I'm not worried about "best practice" methods but more about cleanliness, readability, convenience. Suggestions are still appreciated, however.

Comment: In the sample code, where is "verbose_print" coming from? If it is imported from another module (which holds the config data), the lib module containing "verbose" function could import it as well.

Comment: @MichaelButscher shown in the edit. I import it from a `config.ini` file outside the `lib` folder. I see what you mean by importing the `verbose_print` variable from another module, but I'm not sure if I can import it from the `config.ini` file *into the module* or even change it to a python module itself while keep all functionality (amongst all other scripts).

Comment: Why aren't you using the `logging` module?

Comment: @chepner I never learnt about it, nor heard about it before today. I've been hired for a few months after a few years of inactivity in the programming world. Regardless, after taking a quick look at it, it does seem a bit too clutter-y and complicated, specially when the rest of my coworkers will need to maintain this codebase (they know a lot about data science but not a lot about software engineering specifics).

Comment: I don't know all requirements but I think you could put the config handling (creating "config" object and the first line of shown sample code and more similar lines) in a module to import it. Alternatively you could move this first line to the beginning of "verbose" (maybe with additional code to retrieve the "config" object).

Comment: This is *exactly* what logging is for: log messages that you may want to enable or disable when you start your code. It's not *that* complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `logging` method: you basically want to enable or disable a set of `print` statements based on a value known at startup.

A very simple setup:

```
if config["verbose".getboolean("print"):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.basicConfig()
```

Then use `logging.debug(...)` in place of `verbose_print`.

Comment: I would rather do this instead of what I'm doing right now if I used the logging module for other extra functionality, but this other 4 lines I would need to add at the top of every script regardless, plus the extra import, so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It makes a very big difference: you aren't reinventing the wheel. If line counts scare you, use `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG if config["verbose"].getboolean("print") else logging.WARN)`.